# two way binding for double property with swiftui and observableObject

Tags: swift, swiftui

so - I've got a view that has several textboxes on it.  Basically they represent healthkit values - and reading and writing to healthkit is async.  So I think - I'll create a "model" that handles that and bind it.

so I first try reading it - I create

```swift
public class TodayMeasurements : ObservableObject
{
    
    @Published var weight : Double? = nil
     
    init()
    {

        _ = Health.current_waist().then {
            success in
            self.weight = success
        }
    }
  
}
```

and test it - and it works great.      But then I try to bind it to the textfield, and of course a @Published value only goes one way.   So then I try this:

```swift
       @Binding var weight : Double? = nil
```

and I get 'nil' is not compatible with expected argument type Binding<Value?>.   So at this point I realise I'm obviously doing something wrong.

so the question is - how do I have create a model class where:

- I can bind values in it to text boxes
- I can set the values initially asynchronously
- when the value is changed in the text box, I can call an async function to save it (in this case to healthkit)

Comment: "@Published value only goes one way" no, I'm pretty sure it goes both ways

Comment: Show the code where you attempt to use a binding and/or published in a view. There's just too much unknown and unclear here

Comment: @Published does go both ways. I suspect you're creating your `TodayMeasurement` object incorrectly or that you're using the binding improperly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue maybe how you setup the TextField, try something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var measurements = TodayMeasurements()

    var deci: NumberFormatter {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        return formatter
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Weight", value: $measurements.weight, formatter: deci)
            Text("weight: \((measurements.weight != nil) ? measurements.weight!.debugDescription : "") ")
        }
    }
}
```